# How do I remove Excel copy focus with C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-4.0, clipboard

I created a small app using .NET framework 4 which processes info copied from an Excel spreadsheet and saves the processed data to the clipboard.
The problem is that when the app finishes, Excel's focus is still on the cell from which the data was copied.

My info is in the Office clipboard, but I have to manually remove focus before I can paste it. I would like my app to remove the focus for me, in order to simplify the process. How can this be done?

```
       try
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clipbour Clear Error");
        }                       
        try
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(clipbourholder.ToString(), TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clipbour Paste Error");
        }
```

When information is in clipboard excel has this border around cells, which i dont like because it is active clipboard. I need mine info in active office clipboard. 
[Active clipbourd example](http://s18.postimage.org/knwhuieit/clp_Err.png)

Comment: Can you please reword your question.  Also, can you state the question clearly?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could show the relevant part of your code. You do not need to select a range in order to copy it, so if you stop selecting things (assuming you are) then that might solve your problem.

Comment: Move the focus to something else?

Comment: To get an overall picture... you have developed an application that programmatically opens an excel workbook, then read and processes some cells content, put the processed data into the clipboard, and then the app ends. Once your data is in the clipboard, What do you need to do after that? put the clipboard content into another cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround for that. I generated 64k number and puted to clipbourd and then i could pass my real value. It looks like only mine excel had this issue.